# Get all users from WEB API

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-web-api2

I want to create a service in a WEB API MVC5 project the returns users created.

This works

```
[Route("getUsers")]

    // GET: User
    public List<ApplicationUser> getUsers()
    {
        List<ApplicationUser> users = DbContext.Users.ToList();
        return users;
    }
```

but it returns all the data from the Users, where I'm only interested in returning FullName and Id.

Any suggestions on how to limit the result?

Comment: Create viewmodel class containing only fields from `ApplicationUser` you need and return list of this class instead of `List<ApplicationUser>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three suggestions/enhancements:

- Web API is meant to be used to create RESTful services. Check that you're calling the whole operation using `HTTP/GET` and the route itself says `getXXX`. Change the route to, at least, `/users`.
- Don't return domain objects over the wire. You need to implement [data-transfer objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object). If you've few use cases to return *users* or *one user*, design a class which only have these properties. Also, this is important because objects returned by a `DbContext` are heavy: they also contain tracking information and other things since they're *object proxies*. You'll avoid some overhead and errors while serializing and deserializing.
- Your code should look as follows: `DbContext.Users.Select(u => new UserDto { Id = u.ID, Name = u.Name }).ToList()`. In order to avoid manually mapping your objects, I would suggest that you take a look at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) library.
- Design/implement a domain layer which can be injected/instantiated in your WebAPI in order to encapsulate this complexity and let the WebAPI call something like `userService.ListUsers()`.

Answer (score 0):

Change `DbContext.Users.ToList()` to `DbContext.Users.Select(u => new ApplicationUser() {ID = u.ID, Name = u.Name}).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to use `List`, Do this:

```
[Route("getUsers")]
// GET: User
public IQueryable<object> getUsers()
{
    var users = DbContext.Users.Select( u => new {Id = u.Id, Fullname = u.Fullname});
    return users;
}
```

If you don't have a direct `Fullname` property, you could get if from other properties like `Firstname` and `Lastname` like so:

```
var users = DbContext.Users.Select( u => new {Id = u.Id, Fullname = u.Firstname + " " + u.Lastname});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can project your data using the .Select extension method for IEnumerable.
You could do something like this

```
var users = DbContext.Users(u=> new { Id = u.Id, Fullname = u.Fullname });
return users;
```